# Understanding u-boot configuration step

Tags: configuration, u-boot

I am trying to understand to u-boot configuration process. Actually I want to reconfigure the CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS definition in device's config file. I search that file in include/configs. But I wonder that, how to u-boot determine which config file to use in the compile process ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Before you build U-Boot, you have to configure with a `make <board_name>_defconfig`.  There should be a **board/.../myboard/MAINTAINERS** file that links that defconfig file with an **include/configs/myboard.h** file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how to u-boot determine which config file to use in the compile process ?

U-Boot configuration is an evolving topic , e.g. Kconfig replaced the prior configuration scheme starting with v2014.10-rc1.
You neglect to mention what version of U-Boot that you are using.
The following applies to version 2017.09.

The board's configuration header file is specified by a config variable defined in the **Kconfig** file.
For the Beaglebone Black, **/board/ti/am335x/Kconfig** specifies:

```
config SYS_CONFIG_NAME
    default "am335x_evm"
```

which means **include/configs/am335x_evm.h** is used as the board configuration header file.

This is documented in **doc/README.kconfig**:

```
When adding a new board, the following steps are generally needed:

 [1] Add a header file include/configs/<target>.h
 [2] Make sure to define necessary CONFIG_SYS_* in Kconfig:
       Define CONFIG_SYS_CPU="cpu" to compile arch/<arch>/cpu/<cpu>
       Define CONFIG_SYS_SOC="soc" to compile arch/<arch>/cpu/<cpu>/<soc>
       Define CONFIG_SYS_VENDOR="vendor" to compile board/<vendor>/common/*
         and board/<vendor>/<board>/*
       Define CONFIG_SYS_BOARD="board" to compile board/<board>/*
         (or board/<vendor>/<board>/* if CONFIG_SYS_VENDOR is defined)
       Define CONFIG_SYS_CONFIG_NAME="target" to include
         include/configs/<target>.h
 [3] Add a new entry to the board select menu in Kconfig.
     The board select menu is located in arch/<arch>/Kconfig or
     arch/<arch>/*/Kconfig.
 [4] Add a MAINTAINERS file
     It is generally placed at board/<board>/MAINTAINERS or
     board/<vendor>/<board>/MAINTAINERS
 [5] Add configs/<target>_defconfig
```

The **MAINTAINERS** file is apparently merely documentation that references both the defconfig file(s) and the configuration header file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.
I made following steps for confirm your response. By the way, I work with beaglebone black.

1. I added warning line in am335x_evm.h like `#warning CONFIG_SPL_BUILD IS NOT DEFINED!`.
2. I changed the **MAINTAINERS** file in **boards/ti/am335x**. 
   I changed **include/configs/am335x_evm.h** line in **MAINTAINERS** to **include/configs/pico-imx7d_spl_defconfig** just for test.
3. I executed `make ARCH=arm am335x_boneblack_defconfig`.
4. And lastly I executed `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -j4`.

**RESULT** : I saw `warning: #warning CONFIG_SPL_BUILD IS NOT DEFINED!` in compile logs. And also I checked **include/config.h** after the compile. In this headers, still **am335x_evm.h** is used. So I got your answers wrong or your answer wrong. Could you help me with more information ?.@sawdust